# Did a specific person inspire Lord Byron's poem "She Walks in Beauty"?

Tags: poetry, inspiration, lord-byron

Did a specific person inspire Lord Byron's poem "She Walks in Beauty"?

> She walks in beauty, like the night
> Of cloudless climes and starry skies;

Lord Byron's poem is a classic. Did someone special inspire it, and if so, who?

Comment: Have you checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She_Walks_in_Beauty)? (*while at a ball, Byron met his cousin by marriage through John Wilmot*)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes.

The poem was written in response to seeing his cousin, Lady Wilmot Horton, at a ball.  She is his cousin by marriage, through a man named John Wilmot, governor of Ceylon..

> (3) These stanzas were written by Lord Byron, on returning from a ball-room, where he had seen Mrs. (now Lady) Wilmot Horton, the wife of his relation, the present Govern of Ceylon.  On this occasion Mrs. H. had appeared in mourning, with numerous spangles on her dress – L.E.

From [*The Complete Works of Lord Byron: Reprinted from the Last London Edition*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nEoJAAAAQAAJ&pg=254).